# JMeter variable not being used in POST request

Tags: jmeter

I am extracting several variables from a login response, using "Regular Expression Extractor" post processors. Most of them work when I reuse the variable, but one doesn't.
The regex extractor has the following settings:

```
Apply to: Main sample only
Field to check: Body
Name of variable: id_token
Regular Expression: <input type="hidden" name="id_token" value="([^"]+)"
Template: 
Match No.:
Default Value:
Use empty default value: (unchecked)
```

Then in a later POST HTTP request I use the parameter:

```
Name,   Value,  URL Encode?,    Content-Type,   Include Equals
id_token,   ${id_token_g1}, true,   text/plain, true
```

When running the test in the "View Results Tree" listener the same POST request's POST data contains

```
&id_token=%24%7Bid_token_g1%7D
```

Instead of the value of id_token_g1.
Other variables in the same POST data are being completed correctly.
The Debug PostProcessor from the previous request contains

```
id_token_g1=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IjVEbHphYTlvNEdveWFtWXdLNl9MUS16akFZTSIsImtpZCI6IjVEbHphYTlvNEdveWFtWXdLNl9MUS16akFZTSJ9.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.p8Wn1_SPf2wA1YFby4-ftXGfCtLQaHf6_XXaQJQFF_9SdOHDG2ICVKXs3Jx4UwwyQPDDnKl7rTQINRfb1sfNLnhGsuxr5BoDQaddyG24afT4-quwhl3XDb1jPIMEk-3l-6Rnhdr-UIzHXpMZaaYXE9rdCygI7wqT8REbL8nctQv9GTgh3O751NMjY4FYmj4QDBYrsp9sHJEx_sysMCHPscOm6vnIakKfuVGrVE2qBOQu2PfP3i29npDgNmJ2bmBniljnTMFI57w1vSq8mK2LIYMqoJyy6iudcxAlfRTGzEkezetmH3eIChQIipLUHHb-NmyImtOt-tdUUZXh_Rwq6r7YcwW6zfEPmVFunuHfxc5sB9fZEEzsZLoczB7UeWfBekYGMIK1AKp1BTkQA-kwcqbWIn66Hdjrmepnq3A6nD6pEB-I2tHMgbHIogwHqsGM61OBAGC2y7As3BdF-zepm1m9jISmRX7hiU8u6I1TOhwWIz8VKjlkdmqTQf1lY6I7yAq2Rwtu0zrQ--6el_lB7emX1YvD8whSFpQjI4YNpWJWRZ9ALXC7CudIgN5D4tgzSmEpQrcK-NasXWYf6RMfeDhYTYAbAChgwJ3KwWk6u_5OsX2LgQGbAg23BH9O_9rGg84DTgHM6IMlQG_loX2PnL8B5yqxydbJsz6CBdiLqKg
```

I have the same issue with session_state_g1

```
session_state_g1=XZkcgcg9i_FqlFIS-scHuHqMdm5jepyCSSFkF_S4Dx8.99d68c0a8e802c8767d22fb019bd34b5
```

But not with

```
access_token_g1=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IjVEbHphYTlvNEdveWFtWXdLNl9MUS16akFZTSIsImtpZCI6IjVEbHphYTlvNEdveWFtWXdLNl9MUS16akFZTSJ9.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.Z2RTMN6NGwC1e8bJANmzvA9rUyo03vCpA3TTNylbdR8EpOvaktgHXHjWCFzxlaXeiL-24DlmVoq3qPHRx0u03nr8ZRD2fb9R_OeHxZ-gVr-2D1Ash1f_429J_4U7zjQfAQSOKHHamzTocSl0orLuvQdc9-oAydPCzpp82UbEDwsnQl_E52dK_LEB4eSiV3sB8rSpmZkmnhCmuSh9iUuMEOmA_zIs2cH_exFWjv5WXbZ8gKR-ATrPNuzoDpghMNZs-Of-dZwsaHfSJpV8C12DQ6wZq-w7m6v2szUpgJh1kHafKzM8Gm8-nMAAPV83hbdALFVvsF9tfcLjin3OEdytsfsfRLDEHLh4E-vo-LyAeHV-TKGuvX60-6tdQsSQXY-egVx1W7NiObmLbFzdRGAiV--tk8QHJ8Vf-nVAT00YXeQxEdMl1lqJFNuNOFxoNXL1ud_frUv1c2xwcnCH0hBpt2avWqN72Bj-15j6uube7IPIVp20NpT0M7FujohB-wQLfVJ8d7Ac_AVNScqasdijpTP5DzmsFybvXAu8n0MEcYHYF0-C8_d0EWW7GxpSEeeVFqKNk7JFgXEo1ta_5Yu7XDpwG7evzMFMw49cImZgcQlxrq3oDnl-qo6r9UXOfvS5QoDILU6dqYUpRSS1-Mz4_JbOmEs78v5ixcrm94PfNis
```

I have the same problem if I update the name of the HTTP Request sampler (it shows as ${id_token_g1} in the "View Results Tree" listener)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure your setup is following [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/UserManual/ScopingRules), i.e. you should have setup like:

   - Open Login Page

     - Regular Expression Extractor
   - Perform Login
2. Make sure you have this hidden input with name `id_token` in the response data. JMeter can be configured to store response data in .jtl results file, you need to add next 2 lines in *user.properties* file:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
   ```

   Don't forget to restore the default configuration once you figure out the cause of the problem. See [Results file configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) for more details.
3. [Regular expressions is not the best choice for parsing HTML responses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748) as they can be very fragile in case of markup change (changed order of HTML attributes or the input definition becomes multi-line). So consider switching to [CSS/JQuery Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) instead, the relevant configuration would be something like:

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, you can keep `id_token`
   - CSS/JQuery Expression: `input[id=name]`
   - Attribute: `value`

   In 2nd POST request you can refer the extracted value as `${id_token}`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Using Css/JQuery extractor worked. Debug postprocessor said both the CSS and Regex variables had the same value, and the Regex extractor is at the same level in the tree as the regex extractor, but the variable extracted with the CSS extractor works and the regex one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

1.Follow Jmeter Scoping Rules.

2.To your regular expression you can give template as `$1$` and use `${id_token}` instead of `${id_token_g1}`.

For more information on regular expression extractors
[follow this link.](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/)

[You can use this website](https://regex101.com/) to test your regular expressions.

Let me know if it helps..